# React array mapping wont let me map with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Im using react and im trying to map out part of my object. The skills portion.
i Get the error

```
Uncaught DOMException: The object could not be cloned.
```

I used to just have the name in the array and it worked. But i wanted to add an icon to each. So i turned it into an object.

```
skills: [
  { name: 'Responsive Gallery', icon: <FaTabletAlt size={20} /> },
  { name: '3D Design Tool', icon: <FaTools size={20} /> },
  { name: 'Image Slider on loop', icon: <TfiLayoutSliderAlt size={20} /> },
  { name: 'User Authentication', icon: <GrUserAdmin size={20} /> },
  { name: 'Advanced CSS colour manipulating', icon: <IoMdColorPalette size={20} /> },
],

<article className='outline-2 outline-black outline rounded p-1'>
 <ul className='p-1 grid gap-1'>
  {portfolioItem.skills.map((skill, index) => {
   console.log('skills', skill);
 return 
  <li className='flex gap-2 items-center' key={index}>
   <h4>{skill.icon}</h4>
   <h4>{skill.name}</h4>
  </li>;
 })}
 </ul>
 </article>
```

The page doesnt even open any more.
It did work with just the title.

Comment: Where is the portfolio object?

Comment: If you could make a fiddle, that would help to understand the issue. From the code block above, it looks like you have to wrap the list item inside `()`, otherwise the code will not execute further down after `return`